# Why is the field value not printing with the println?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following class definition, instance creation, and printing a field of the instance:

```
class Rental (location: String, monthlyRent: Float) {
    var location: String = ""
        get () = field
        set (value) { field = value }
}


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        println("Hello World")
        var myRental = Rental("12341.132,34314", 234.4f)
        println("""My rental is! ${myRental.location}""")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

The print statement only prints "My rental is!" in Logcat and not the rest. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the `location` parameter of your constructor. The `location` property is being initialized with `""`. If you want to use a constructor parameter to initialize a property, you need to explicitly do so:

```
class Rental (location: String, monthlyRent: Float) {
    var location: String = location // see here
        get () = field
        set (value) { field = value }
}
```

Side note: your custom `get()` and `set()` are entirely redundant to the default behavior for a property, so they can be eliminated.

Also, you can define the constructor parameter to also be a property by putting `var` or `val` in front of it, which is simpler:

```
class Rental (var location: String, var monthlyRent: Float) {
}
```

Simple data-holding classes like this should be defined as `data` classes so they'll automatically have convenient `toString()` generated for you, as well as `copy()` if you need it.

```
data class Rental (val location: String, val monthlyRent: Float)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're setting the value of `location` variable to an empty string. Also, fields in your constructor are unused. Here is how it will look in Java:

```java
public class Rental {

  private String location = "";

  public Rental(String location, float monthlyRent) {
  }

  // location getters and setters
}
```

You can make use of Kotlin's [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) which create getters, setters, `equals`, `toString` and `copy` methods. Also, I suggest to make `Rental` class immutable my making every variable `val` instead of `var`. So, using data classes your code may look like

```kotlin
data class Rental(val location: String, val monthlyRent: Float)

// your main activity
```